# how to call a directive onclick of a button from a component in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

On click of a image i am opening image popup gallery, on popup i have to apply image zoom. for zoom I created directive which is calling onload but not when popup opens.

How to call directive when popup comes?

First i am calling a component from component i am calling directive based on some conditions like below,

```
<div *ngIf="hirusImage; else normalImage " >
    <div >
    <div id="seadragon-viewer" nwImageZoom [primaryPicture]="primaryPicture" style="float:left;width:500px;height: 333px;color: #333;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

nwImageZoom is my directive,

any solutions will be appreciated thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can use the concept of @HostListener and @HostBinding for calling the directive on the click,

this code will help you.

```js
    import { Directive, HostListener, HostBinding } from '@angular/core'

    @Directive({
       selector:'[nwImageZoom]'
    })

    export class NwImageZoomDirective{

    constructor(){}

    // here you can add the css class you want add for zooming for that we use  
//  isZoom is the variable which decide whether the class will be add or not.]

@HostBinding('class.zoom') isZoom=false;

    enter code here
// here you can attached the 'toggleZoom' function to @HostListener and the 
// inside @HostListener you can pass the Event like-'click'

@HostListener('click') toggleZoom(){
    this.isZoom=!this.isZoom;
}
```

```
enter code here
```

Comment: not working...
my question is directive is calling only first time when page loads but not when i click a button then HTML pis calling but from that html same directive should call but it is  not happening..